# Php array of objects holding objects. Add a variable to an existing object

Tags: php, arrays, object, recursion, loops

I want to build an array of page objects which have children

I have two functions one which creates parent links.

I itereate through the parent links and find children.

I want to add an attribut which is an array of children objects to the parent links.

If possible I would like to recurse over each child until no children are found.

I hope this makes sense.

```
function get_links(){
   $links = array();
   $parent_links = $this->pages_model->get_by_parent(0);//where parent_id = 0;
   $count = 0;
   if(isset($parents_links)&&(count($parent_links)>0)){
       foreach($parent_links as $l){
           $children = $this->get_child_links($l->id);//array _ push results
           if($children != false){
               $l->children = $children;
           }else{
               $l->children = FALSE;
           }
           unset($children);
       }
   }
   return $parent_links;
}

function get_child_links($parent_id){
   $links = $this->pages_model->get_by_parent($parent_id);
   return $links;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, dont do this

```
function get_child_links($parent_id){
   $links = $this->pages_model->get_by_parent($parent_id);
   return $links;
}
```

do this

```
function get_child_links($parent_id){
   return $this->pages_model->get_by_parent($parent_id);
}
```

It speeds up the engine a tiny bit